Keycloak: service accounts gets 403 responses on newly created realm
I am trying to create new realms with roles, users, and other configuration using a Java client. For this purpose, I have set up a service account in the master realm, using OIDC and attaching all realm roles that I could find to it:

I am then using this account to connect to Keycloak via the Java API, from within a Quarkus application. The code tries to create a new realm, then add roles, users, clients, etc to it.
On my local development setup, this process fully works. But I have tried to replicate it on a server, and there the client is able to create realms, but trying to add a role (the first step after the realm creation) fails with forbidden access (HTTP 403).
So far I have tried:

making sure both setups use the same Keycloak version. They both run Docker image quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.6.
checking the startup configuration if there is something that could cause it. The remote has some additional setup to use a production database and run behind a reverse proxy, but none of that seems related.
comparing the client setup on my local, working configuration with the remote, non-working one by clicking through all screens that seemed relevant. I could not see any difference apart from ordering of roles or similar elements that I assume have set semantics.
running Keycloak with debug logging on and reading the logs. I can see it fails in org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.permissions.RolePermissions.requireManage(RolePermissions.java:370) but that doesn't seem to tell me anything new, nor did anything else in the logs seem relevant (there is quite a bit of logging, so I might have missed something).
downloading exports of the master realm in both setups and somewhat normalizing them while looking at a diff (replace UUIDs with hard-coded string, remove realms not shared, re-order some lists) - so far I have found no difference, but it's rather tedious to normalize the ordering, so I haven't done all and I may have made mistakes.

One difference is that my local setup is not behind a reverse proxy, and on the remote the access is a bit more complex: the public facing reverse proxy uses a different hostname (set as KC_HOSTNAME) than the API access as the API is not exposed to the public. The account management software I wrote uses a Docker bridge network where the Keycloak instance is just known via the host name keycloak. KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT is false.
These are the full environment settings for the container:
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=...
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=...
KC_DB=postgres
KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/keycloak
KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
KC_DB_PASSWORD=...
KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
KC_PROXY_HEADERS=forwarded
KC_HOSTNAME=https://...external.location...
KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
KC_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG

What could cause the 403 on a realm that the client just managed to create itself?

It turns out the difference between the two setups was the behaviour of the client in development mode. While the code running was exactly the same, in development mode it would delete any previously existing realms.
I would not expect that to make a difference, but it seems that the session will have permissions to the realms that existed when it started, keyed on the realm names. That means that if a realm of the same name existed at the start of the session, the client would have permissions on a new realm of the same name. And during testing the names were re-used.
The behaviour is not what I expect, so I raised an issue in the GitHub project. The ticket creates a test case with more detail of the observed behaviour.
The workaround is to establish a new client connection after the realm was created.
